# SQL Server (TSQL) Select first value if exists, otherwise select other

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like a union query where the second query is used only if the first does not return any results.

a simple example...

table

```
create table tbl (
   name varchar(3),
   lang varchar(3)
);

insert into tbl (name, lang) values ('foo', 'en');
insert into tbl (name, lang) values ('foo', 'es');
insert into tbl (name, lang) values ('bar', 'en');
insert into tbl (name, lang) values ('baz', 'en');
```

query

```
SELECT name, lang
FROM   tbl
WHERE  lang = 'es'
UNION ALL
SELECT name, lang
FROM   tbl
WHERE  lang = 'en'
```

output

```
name   lang
-----------
foo     es
foo     en
bar     en
baz     en
```

expected

```
name   lang
-----------
foo     es
bar     en
baz     en
```

Comment: Use a WHERE clause in the second query that will filter out any rows that would be in the first query.

Comment: Are you actually trying to retrieve an English default translation if the desired translation (ES in the example) does not exist?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this:

```
SELECT name, lang
FROM (
   SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY CASE WHEN lang = 'es' THEN  1 ELSE 2 END) AS rn
   FROM tbl ) t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

You can adjust to `CASE` clause within `OVER` to accomodate any other language.

Comment: What about for languages es, en, de ?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan The `CASE` can easily be adjusted provided that there are a few more other languages. Although I don't think the OP is interested in more than two languages.

Comment: `CASE WHEN lang = 'es' THEN 1 WHEN lang = 'en' THEN 2 WHEN lang = 'de' THEN 3 ELSE 4 END`

Comment: (+1) I prefer this answer over the others (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9cfc7/2)... Perhaps having `when lang = 'en' then 2` always there to default to english is best.

Answer (score 4):

Use `Row_Number()` window function.

```
select name, lang
from
(
SELECT name, lang,row_number(partition by name order by order_column) RN
FROM   tbl
) a
where RN=1
```

Keep what ever `column` which helps you to find the `first` value per `Name` `order by` in `row_number`

Comment: I don't think this will select the es column over the en column as written...  Prefer the concept, just not quite there...

Comment: This is a better overall solution.  You should either add a priority to the table to guarantee expected results or add a unique constraint to prevent this scenario before it happens.

Comment: This principle won't be extensible to cases where there are more than 2 languages and priority is not determined by alphabetical order.   But if a priority column is added, then it could be used.

Comment: I was talking about an actual value on the table records not the hard-coded priority I had.  So every record in that table specified its 'priority' or weight.  The sort by that and choose the highest or lowest, whichever makes the most sense.

Answer (score 4):

Since the entities are not defined in an external table but "inline" I had to make a "starting point" by seeing which are the entities we are talking about (the `SELECT DISTINCT` inner query).

Then, starting from the entities, we try (`LEFT JOIN`) to find a row with the desired language and also a row with the fallback language. We then use `COALESCE` to "prioritize" the translations (desired language first, then fallback second - if desired is `NULL` - and finally some hardcoded default if not even the fallback is not there).

```
DECLARE @lang varchar(3) = 'es'
DECLARE @fallbackLang varchar(3) = 'en'

SELECT
    Entities.name,
    COALESCE(WantedLang.lang, FallbackLang.lang, 'N/A')
FROM
    (
      SELECT
        DISTINCT name
      FROM
          tbl
    ) Entities
    LEFT JOIN tbl WantedLang ON Entities.name = WantedLang.name AND WantedLang.lang = @lang
    LEFT JOIN tbl FallbackLang ON Entities.name = FallbackLang.name AND FallbackLang.lang = @fallbackLang
```

[SQL Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1bf5f/20)

Answer (score 0):

Use a WHERE clause in the second query that will filter out any rows that would be in the first query. –

```
SELECT name, lang
FROM   tbl
WHERE  lang = 'es'
UNION ALL
SELECT name, lang
FROM   tbl
WHERE  lang = 'en'
AND name NOT IN (
 SELECT name
 FROM   tbl
 WHERE  lang = 'es'
)
```